# AWS DynamoDB table for retrieval of video / photo content in date order

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, data-modeling

I am about to create a DynamoDB table for my Instagram-like video / photo sharing application. The purpose of this table is to feed the grid view of all the user's posts in date order. We all know the use case :)

Clearly, the GUID (for the video or photo) will be my primary key. I'll have a structure that looks like this (partial) JSON for initially loading the table:

```
{
    "VideoCatalog": [
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "Guid": "67459e53-21bb-4a7d-8f7a-18e4cd165c44",
                    "Timestamp": "20160314",
                    "ThumbnailName": "20160314-TheWind_tumb.0000000.jpg",
                    "Title": "The Wind"
                }
            }
        },
        ...
}
```

Probably not important, but the GUID corresponds to an S3 folder within which are the various video "assets", including various formats for adaptive multi-bit rate video-on-demand streaming. I'll be using the AWS JavaScript SDK for accessing the table, etc.

What I'm unsure about is whether or not I want to specify the `timestamp` as a sort key to help in returning results (eventually via lazy loading / pagination) in date order with most recent first.

In the reading I've done on sort keys (e.g., [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/using-sort-keys-to-organize-data-in-amazon-dynamodb/)) I'm unsure if that's their intended function.

As the DynamoDB guide says:

> In a table that has a partition key and a sort key, it's possible for two items to have the same partition key value.

That's definitely not the use case for my data.

Any suggestions on retrieving items in date order from a DynamoDB table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If guid is your primary key it does not make sense to have date as secondary key since in my understanding of your use case there can be only one resource par guid.

however this is how i would have designed the schema solving the your use cases.

```
| userId (PK) |  Timestamp (sortKey) | resourceid         |
| 123         |   12343212           |  guid1             |
| 123         |   12343215           |  guid2             |
```

Comment: Well, your answer answered every logical problem with my thinking about the DynamoDB model.. and now I'm embarrassed! haha. I guess I was thinking that each user would have their own VideoCatalog, but that's neither here nor there. You seem to be exactly right in that I should not make the Guids the PK, especially since I would likely never query on a Guid in that manner. Thanks for totally changing my thinking on this problem!!!